# Why are there four workers in a Supermarket, and what changes if I fire some of them?

Tags: tropico-4

In the Tropico 4 DLC Modern Times, you get a Supermarket: it's like a Marketplace in that it serves as a food-distribution point (so people don't have to hike out to the farms), but can store more food, change the type of food it sells (healthy/junk food), and employs 4 people. Marketplaces only ever require a single worker, and I haven't yet seen people starving because they were waiting in line.

In some Modern Times campaign missions, you start with a Supermarket. Early in a game, tying up four high-school-educated workers in a Supermarket is a waste of educated workers. **I usually fire three of them so I can use those educated workers elsewhere, but what's the effect of this on the building's services?** Do fully-staffed Supermarkets serve people faster, or have a higher service quality, or serve higher-quality food, or what?

Comment: High school workers are considered educated? What a strange game.

Comment: It's a game about a banana republic. Uneducated citizens are the norm, and just working in a factory requires a high school education. Since factories can be hilariously profitable, building a high school and increasing the number of educated citizens is really important.

Comment: @decency Education levels are 'uneducated', 'high school' and 'college education' and determine what kind of jobs said citizen can perform. Schools and colleges are expensive to build early on but nearly all of the sustainably profitable exports require at least high-school educated workers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that the number of workers has an [effect on it's work modes](http://forum.kalypsomedia.com/showthread.php?tid=14219&pid=125715#pid125715).

> Lyubo_Haemimont Wrote:  The number of workers does have a significance in the Supermarket. Mainly for the effects of its work modes.

Since the work modes affect food quality vs. life expectancy, more workers would make that Junk food / Healthy food choice more meaningful.

Comment: So if it is in "normal" mode, there is no effect?

Answer (score 3):

Firing workers in a building always decreases the amount of people that can be served at the same time or reduces the amount of goods produced per cycle.

Comment: The Supermarket doesn't have any slots for people being served, though. Does that still apply?